# Method 'Intersect' of object '_Global' failed inside a Sheet's module -- ActiveSheet not recognised

Tags: vba, excel, intersect

I currently use a self made spreadsheet to clock my day. Every time I insert a new activity, it should calculate the time taken me on the last activity.

It works fine as is when I create a new spreadsheet everyday, however now I'm thinking to consolidate the spreadsheet into a monthly file.

I have a macro button on the same spreadsheet that refreshes my pivot table which summarizes my tasks.

Unfortunately, once I make a copy of the worksheet and tries to refresh the pivot table, it gives me an error message: `Method 'Intersect' of object '_Global' failed`

My current coding is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Stamp Date

Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range

Set WorkRng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), Target)

If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            If Rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Start" Then
                Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Rng.Offset(-1, 1)
                Else: Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                Rng.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
            End If
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

'Time Format

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or Target.HasFormula Then GoTo errHandler
    On Error Resume Next
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C3:C33")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.NumberFormat = "H:MM AM/PM"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

On Error GoTo errHandler

    If WorkRng.Offset(0, 1) > 0 Then
        WorkRng.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Exit Sub

errHandler:     ActiveCell.Select

End Sub
```

The debug highlights: `Set WorkRng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), Target)`

Being a beginner at VBA, these codes are mostly copied from different places. As a result, I don't even know what went wrong. Any assistance would be very greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like "another ActiveSheet problem", if you try to intersect two or more ranges from a different worksheets - here's your error. Try to get rid of `ActiveSheet` if possible. BTW, I think problem occured when fresh copy of sheet became ActiveSheet. From this point you can try to compare `if ActiveSheet is Target.Worksheet` and if not - just `Target.Worksheet.Activate` (don't do this).

Comment: where do you put your `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` sub?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ActiveSheet` inside of a Sheet's module, you have to reference that Sheet with `Me` (like you would do in a UserForm) :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Stamp Date
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Me.Range("B:B"), Target)

    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each Rng In WorkRng
            If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
                If Rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Start" Then
                    Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Rng.Offset(-1, 1)
                    Else: Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                    Rng.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "H:MM AM/PM"
                End If
            Else
                Rng.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    'Time Format
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Or Target.HasFormula Then GoTo errHandler

    On Error Resume Next
        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C3:C33")) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.NumberFormat = "H:MM AM/PM"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    If WorkRng.Offset(0, 1) > 0 Then
        WorkRng.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Exit Sub

errHandler
    Me.ActiveCell.Select
End Sub
```